# How to determine the CDF(Cumulative Distribution Function) of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider an event E=choosing a rational number randomly. Then the sample space would be the set of all rational numbers. Now, consider a random variable which maps each rational number to the same rational number. Then ,my question is how the CDF will look like?

Comment: It depends on *how* a rational number is chosen "randomly." Certainly they cannot be all equally likely.

Comment: why choosing a random rational no. is not equally likely?

Comment: Coz Kolmogorov said so and everyone listened.

Comment: Because if any rational has probability $p\gt 0$ of being chosen, then we violate the fact that probabilities are always $\le 1$. And if $p=0$ then we violate countable additivity, that the probability of a countable disjoint union is the sum of the probabilities.

Comment: If for example we enumerate $\mathbb{Q},$ we could define $\mathbb{P}(q_n) = C/n^2.$ In this case the CDF would be a cadlag function with countably many jumps. One jump for every rational number. Do you ask for some particular properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the start of my approach, but I'm not able to finish it.

If all numbers have an equal chance, you can especially write $P(E = -x) = P(E = x)$. Use that the rational numbers are countable, and define $q(i)$ for $i\in \mathbb{N}_0$ as follows:
$$
q(i) = \begin{cases}
0 & i = 0\\
\text{The i/2'th rational number > 0} & i\in 2\mathbb{N}_1\\
-1 * \text{The (i+1)/2'th rational number > 0} & i\in 2\mathbb{N}_1-1
\end{cases}
$$
Now use that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(E = q(i)) = 1$ and $P(E=q(i)) = P(E=q(j))$ $\forall i,j\geq 0$